# Storing configuration data in flash memory

Tags: memory-management, microcontroller, eeprom

I want to store some values into internal flash memory like config data, i was able to create a section and able write and read data, but when load program/flash code into it the whole flash memory is getting earised

I was expecting to have the data   after flash a program

Comment: flash is "erased" in blocks and written in bits, in general.  You can...sometimes...flip more bits after the erase over time (if it erases to all ones. then you can write 0xaa then SOMETIMES change that to say 0x44.    but in general you want to do this you need to either isolate a whole block for this, or if there is other info in that block you copy the whole block to ram make your modifications to ram, erase the block and write the block back from what you stored in ram.

Comment: You may be able to configure your programming tool so that it erases and reprograms only the program code area instead of the whole flash.  Ensure your configuration data is in a flash block/sector that is separate from the program code so that the configuration data doesn't get erased with the program code.